# What is the difference between HLayout and HStack in smartgwt?

Tags: smartgwt

I have been using smartgwt for some time, What is the factor that i have to consider to choose between a Stack and Layout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference the two is, if you use HStack, the size of the HStack will be fixed as per the browser window size.

While in case of HLayout, the size given to HLayout is adjusted everytime you resize your browser window.

For more information on this, please visit these links & see the code samples & Overview:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_layout
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_stack